# react-redux state undefined of props - functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

In my redux application, I'm trying to use react-redux and react-navigation together :

```
<Provider store={store}>
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen name="Dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Store" component={Store} />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      </Provider>
```

And my store looks like this :

```
function Store({props, dispatch, navigation, route}) {
  console.debug(props);//this is undefined
}
...
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    cartItems: state.cartItems,
  };
};

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    ...
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps())(Store);
```

**I don't know why props is returning undefined ?**

I have used react-navigation and react-redux separately, ever encountered this problem. Made this cocktail, now facing this problem.

Comment: Store is going to receive `props` as the first argument, you could instead extract the props like: `function Store({ cartItems }) `, otherwise just simply: `function Store(props)`

Comment: @segFault pardon me but is props going to be the first argument or the only argument? Because your suggestion of extracting objects from it definitely suggests so that it shall be the only argument

Comment: @JayD yea props should be the only thing getting passed to a functional/state-less component in react. Check [the docs here](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components) "...  it accepts a single “props” (which stands for properties) object argument ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your component code is slightly off, `props` is passed as the first argument so, you do not need to extract `props` the way you are doing it now.

For example:

```
function Store(props) {
  console.debug(props);
}
```

Alternatively, you could extract your props within the function definition like:

```
function Store({ cartItems }) {
  console.debug(cartItems);
}
```

Comment: it worked... but it's really odd that I have to declare every element as props, it would be better if it could be declared as map, just like state or prop...

Comment: If you don't like the name of the argument being `props` it can be anything, for example `function Store(map)` would also work (if you then also use `map` in your code). "props" is just the standard name for React components to make it easy to refer to.